# Recursion counter inside a C++ function

Tags: c++, recursion

Doing an assignment on recursive functions at the moment.
Was asked to do a Fibonacci program and did so with out much issue.
But I'm need to make a counter for it, and here is where I'm getting stuck.

I've got this function

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if( n == 0 )
    {
        //my fibonacci code 
    }
    else if( n == 1 )
    {
        //my fibonacci code
    }
    else 
    { 
        //my fibonacci code
    }
}
```

So how to I add a counter to this? Ever time I add a counter it returns the wrong number.

*Edit*  Just to clarify, my function works fine generating the Fibonacci numbers. I just wanted to add a counter inside the function so I can see how many times it is being called every time I want it to generate a Fibonacci number.

I have since tried one of the methods below where I initialise a counter in the main function then increment it in the recursion but don't know if the number is correct. For example it is saying that I'm calling the function 609 times if my Fibonacci number is 610, is that correct?

Comment: How do you add the counter that is not working?

Comment: You first have to add the recursive calls where the comments are.
Basically n will turn into a counter of the recursion depth.
What do you want to count? Invocations of f?

Comment: Use in-function `static` variable for the counter.

Comment: You don't need any counters here!

Comment: There's a counter in here? interesting...

Comment: See the how recursion can be implemented for [finonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) You don't need counters here

Comment: I don't think that is the point. I think his assignment is to add a function *call* counter for the number of times the function is called (the initial call and all the recursive calls). Does that sound right, @user2661167 ?

Comment: Yes, counting makes only sense for invocations/calls to the function and the recursion depth. But he still needs to add the beef first.

Comment: @mvw I agree, it is unclear whether "did so with out much issue" means he has a working sequence generator or not (this code certainly is not). But OPs tend to think their code is some state-secret and show a rather odd propensity to not paste *real* code, so sometimes it isn't easy to know for sure until you really squeeze awhile.

Comment: @PetrBudnik How will you reset the counter when the top function has returned?

Comment: @NeilKirk I will dump it to screen or file or whatever when I'm in most inner function call right before unwinding of the recursion. I can reset it to `0` right there as well for the next calculation. The counter is understood as counter for the number of recursive calls to the function.

Comment: @user2661167 I added a section refering to your latest edit. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you just need the count for demonstration purposes, right?
Counting the calls should be easily achievable by passing in a counter variable by reference, and increasing it once at the beginning of each call, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

// ...

int fibonacci(int n, int &count)
{
    ++count;
    // other code ...

    // and every time you call fibonacci recursively,
    // simply pass in the same reference, like so:
    if (...) {
        fibonacci (new_n, count);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // call it with an int variable initialized to 0:
    int fibCnt = 0;
    fibonacci(10, fibCnt);
    std::cout << "Function was called "<<fibCnt<<" times"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the only logical deduction I can see for the question as (vaguely) stated from the OP. Second only to factorial, the fibbonccci sequence is available in about a million websites in code-form. I find it difficult to fathom his trouble is implementing the algorithm, and rather, it is likely *this* he's struggling with.

Comment: @WhozCraig exactly my train of thought ;)

Comment: just to clarify, my function to make the fibonacci numbers work fine. I just wanted a counter inside the function to see how many times it is being called for each Fibonacci number I'm generating.

Comment: @user2661167 and that's exactly what my solution provides, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any counters. Your code is already almost there

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if( n == 0 )
    {
        return f_0
    }
    else if( n == 1 )
    {
        return f_1
    }
    else 
    { 
        return f_n using recursion
    }
}
```

As the Fibonacci numbers are defined via recursion, the last case is obvious. The other two are needed only to close the recursion relations, i.e. to avoid the last case to result in an infinite loop.

Comment: And fyi, @mvw, the [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) sequence starts at (0,1), *not* (1,1). It makes a difference when asking for the Nth number in the sequence.

Comment: I would need to look it up. I had a version in mind where n is more a numbering (starting from 0), but I guess you mean the one for example with the rabbits mating, where it depicts the number of rabbits.

Comment: @mvw Link was provided in prior comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig Funny, my error was not unrelated to the task, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the code first. I give you the recursion equations:

```
fib(0) = *deleted*
fib(1) = *deleted*
fib(n) = *deleted*
```

Your counter (which you should still specify in your question) can be usually implemented by a global variable defined outside the function but be changed within the function.

Referring to the question's edit:

Your number is not good. To not spoil your task more, I give you the answer in Erlang, so you still have some work left to figure out how to get it right in your C++ task. :-)

```
-module(fib).

-export([f/1]).

%% returns a tupel { fibonacci value, number function calls }
f(0) -> {0, 1};
f(1) -> {1, 1};
f(X) -> 
    {F1, C1} = f(X - 1),  %% decompose tuple
    {F2, C2} = f(X - 2),
    {F1 + F2, C1 + C2}.  %% return value
```

Running this from a shell gives:

```
Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c("q:/doc/erlang/fib", [{outdir, "q:/doc/erlang/"}]).
{ok,fib}
2> fib:f(0).
{0,1}
3> fib:f(1).
{1,1}
4> fib:f(2).
{1,2}
5> fib:f(3).
{2,3}
6> fib:f(4).
{3,5}
7> fib:f(5).
{5,8}
8> fib:f(6).
{8,13}
9> fib:f(7).
{13,21}
10> fib:f(15).
{610,987}
11>
```

Thus I get 987 function calls to get at the F(15) = 610 value.

The interesting bit here is, in the comments we talked about the proper start conditions for the Fibonacci recursion F (the situation is similar to differential equations, a different start point gets you on a different trajectory / solution).

I got it wrong with F(0) = 1 and F(1) = 1, while @WhozCraig correctly pointed out it should be F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1.

If you look at the Erlang code above you see that the calculation of the series which yields the number of function calls is a Fibonacci type one as well (adding the last two members of the series), but that one is the one with the start values 1 and 1! :-)

Comment: @Walter OK, i retracted it - i hoped he was stuck in the programming not the maths.

Comment: sorry, cannot undo my down-voting ... you have to edit again.

Comment: It's all good I managed to complete the code before I read the reply. I put the counter in the wrong sections before and was messing up the count.

Answer (score 0):

Using struct could be the answer.

```
struct factorial
{
  factorial() : counter(0)
  {}

  uint64_t foo(uint64_t x) {
    ++counter;

    if(x < 2)
      return 1;
    else
      return x * foo(x - 1);
  }

  template <class T>
  T operator()(const T& x) {
    return foo(x);
  }

  uint64_t counter;
} factorial;
```

In this case, `foo` is the factorial function. but doesn't have that name, because the usage of the struct will be.

```
// output and calls
struct factorial foo;
std::cout << foo(5) << "\n";
std::cout << foo.counter << "\n";

// output
std::cout << factorial(5) << "\n";
```

Comment: Just change foo, with fibonacci recursive implementation and the name with `fibonacci`